# How to fetch Message from MessageReactionAddEvent

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Currently, am trying to make a music discord bot and it should display the list of music it is currently playing.
The message list have a left and right arrow emoji which the person can use it to move through the list of music that is playing.

I am unable to get the message that the person just added a reaction to.

```
@override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event){
I need to get the reacted message here.
}
```

I have tried doing `event.getMessage()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the channel which the message was in, then fetch the message itself using the message's ID with [`channel.getMessageById()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA3-Legacy/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/MessageChannel.html#getMessageById-long-):

```
@override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event){
    Message message = event.getChannel().getMessageById(event.getMessageId()).complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a shorter way to do this though? This line is relatively long...

Comment: Try to make the statement into a function. Call that function each time you want to fetch the message.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`retrieveMessageById`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#retrieveMessageById(java.lang.String)) in combination with [`queue`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue(java.util.function.Consumer)) to retrieve it asynchronously:

```java
@override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
    event.getChannel().retrieveMessageById(event.getMessageId()).queue(message -> {
        System.out.println(message.getContentDisplay());
    });
}
```

This will avoid blocking code which might slow your bot down. The only difference in your code is that you write the code which uses the message in the callback of queue. Generally the use of `complete` is discouraged because it might lock up your event thread for an unpredictable time frame.

Alternatively you can also edit or delete messages with only the ID which can be useful in a paginated message scenario:

- [`deleteMessageById(id)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#deleteMessageById(java.lang.String))
- [`editMessageById(id, newContent)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#editMessageById(java.lang.String,java.lang.CharSequence))